# Spring Boot Neo4J has no property with propertyKey="__type__"

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

Am using spring boot 1.2.3.RELEAE and spring-data-neo4j 3.2.2.RELEASE which uses Neo4J 2.1.5.

I am trying to build a graph of Stations which are connected to other stations via "CONNECTED_TO" relationship. The relationship has "distance" as a property. Later on we are planning to do dijkstra's algorithm on the graph. But anyway... this is what we have:

```
@NodeEntity
@TypeAlias("Station")
public class Station {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Indexed
    public String name;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    public String tlc;

    public double gps_x;
    public double gps_y;

    @RelatedTo(type = "CONNECTED_TO", direction = OUTGOING)
    public Set<Station> connectedTo = new HashSet<>();

    @Fetch
    @RelatedToVia(type = "CONNECTED_TO", direction = OUTGOING)
    public Set<ConnectedTo> connections = new HashSet<>();

    // getter + setters
}

@RelationshipEntity(type = "CONNECTED_TO")
public class ConnectedTo {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Fetch
    @StartNode
    private Station fromStation;

    @Fetch
    @EndNode
    private Station toStation;

    private double distance;

    // getter + setters
}
```

And have a stations.csv with 2K plus stations... here is a sample:

```
name,tlc,gps_y,gps_x
Alexandra Palace,AAP,-0.120235219,51.59792231
Achanalt,AAT,-4.913851155,57.60959445
Aberdare,ABA,-3.443083402,51.71505622
Altnabreac,ABC,-3.706280166,58.38814697
```

And then for the relations ships (5K plus) we have station_connections.csv.. here is a sample:

```
name,from_tlc,to_tlc,distance
Alexandra Palace,AAP,BOP,0.7
Alexandra Palace,AAP,HRN,0.9
Alexandra Palace,AAP,NSG,1.5
Achanalt,AAT,ACN,6.5
Achanalt,AAT,LCC,4.2
Aberdare,ABA,CMH,0.8
Altnabreac,ABC,FRS,8.1
Altnabreac,ABC,SCT,9.1
```

Then I have a import service to import the CSVs

Firstly, I import the stations from stations.csv. This works fine. This is the code to import it:

```
@Transactional
public void importStations(CsvReader stationsFile) throws IOException {
    // id,terminalName,name,installed,locked,temporary,lat,lng
    while (stationsFile.readRecord()) {

        Station station = new Station()
                .setName(stationsFile.get("name").toUpperCase())
                .setTlc(stationsFile.get("tlc").toUpperCase())
                .setGps_y(asDouble(stationsFile.get("gps_y")))
                .setGps_x(asDouble(stationsFile.get("gps_x")));

        stationRepository.save(station);
    }
}
```

Secondly, I want to import station connections from station_connections.csv. using the following code:

```
@Transactional
public void importConnections(CsvReader stationsFile) throws IOException {
        // name,from_tlc,to_tlc,distance

        while (stationsFile.readRecord()) {

            String from_tlc = stationsFile.get("from_tlc").toUpperCase();
            String to_tlc = stationsFile.get("to_tlc").toUpperCase();
            String distance = stationsFile.get("distance");

            Station fromStation = stationRepository.findByTlc(from_tlc);
            Station toStation = stationRepository.findByTlc(to_tlc);

            if (fromStation != null && toStation != null) {

                // need to do this get the connected stations...!!!
                template.fetch(fromStation.getConnectedTo());
                template.fetch(toStation.getConnectedTo());

                fromStation.addStation(toStation);

                template.save(fromStation);

                System.out.println(from_tlc + " connected to: " + to_tlc);
            }
        }
    }
```

So when it tries to import the connections I get the following error: `RELATIONSHIP[4434] has no property with propertyKey="__type__".`

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: RELATIONSHIP[4434] has no property with propertyKey="__type__".
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.RelationshipProxy.getProperty(RelationshipProxy.java:195)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.AbstractIndexBasedTypeRepresentationStrategy.readAliasFrom(AbstractIndexBasedTypeRepresentationStrategy.java:126)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.TRSTypeAliasAccessor.readAliasFrom(TRSTypeAliasAccessor.java:36)
    at
```

So I basically I am baffled at this error and would appreciate some help.

If there is a better way of doing this please do let me know.

GM

Answer (score 0):

Can you check Relationships with id 4434 ? If it really doesn't have that property, and what kind of relationship it is.

It means that SDN couldn't load a relationship mapped to a Java type because somehow the type-information was not stored on it.

You can do that after the fact with `template.postEntityCreation(rel, ConnectedTo.class);`